# Why does the UNC pathway not work when running batch file from console?

Tags: c#, command-line, batch-file

I have a very simple batch file:

```
echo Text > Test.txt
```

This file is saved here:

> `R:\Testing123.bat`
>   full UNC pathway is
>   `\\imfile\depart$\DB\Testing123.bat`

In my console application the following runs:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"R:\";
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"Testing123.bat";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

This does not run if I use the full pathway:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true  ;
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"\\imfile\depart$\DB\";
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"Testing123.bat";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

Can I not use these UNC pathways for the WorkingDirectory property? I thought when programming it was always best practice to use these pathways?

**EDIT**

Using one of the suggestions I now have the following which unformtunately still doesn't work :

```
{

    Process myP = new Process();
    myP.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    string myString = @"pushd \\imfile\depart$\DB";
    myP.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    myP.StartInfo.Arguments = myString;
    myP.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myP.Start();

    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true  ;
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"\\imfile\depart$\DB";
    //myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"R:\";
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"Testing123.bat";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.Start();

}
```

Comment: Command Line doesn't recognize UNC Pathways.  You'll have to use a drive letter like in that first block of code.  Ideally it would be temporarily created in the batch file itself so it doesn't run into problems with user settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bat-files are executed via cmd.exe, which (by default) does not allows UNC paths as "working directory". However, you may change this behavoir via registry.

```
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
 "DisableUNCCheck"=dword:00000001
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276

This information is known to me from [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) [TechInfo Section 2.2](http://farmanager.com/svn/trunk/docs/ENG/TechInfo.txt).